# is the code of this reinforcement learning example correct?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am trying to learn reinforcement learning from an article on Wolfram.com, and after several days I still cannot quite get everything right. Now I wonder about the correctness of a piece of code given in this article.
The article title is "Train an Agent in a Reinforcement Learning Environment
", with the link https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/neural-network-framework/train-an-agent-in-a-reinforcement-learning-environment.html.en?footer=lang.

In the article, after training is complete the article animates the trained policy using the following code which I wonder whether is correct (right after the sentence "Animate the environment with the trained policy net ..."):

```
DeviceExecute[env, "Reset"];
ListAnimate[
  Table[(DeviceExecute[env, "Step", 
     DeviceExecute[env, trained[DeviceRead[env]["ObservedState"]]]]; 
    DeviceExecute[env, "Render"]), 50]];
```

In this piece of code,

```
trained
```

is the trained neural network that give a policy choice between 'Left' and 'Right'
given the current observed state of env.
So trained[DeviceRead[env]["ObservedState"]] is equal to either 'Left' or 'Right'.
My question is,
shouldn't

```
DeviceExecute[env, "Step", 
     DeviceExecute[env, trained[DeviceRead[env]["ObservedState"]]
```

be simply

```
DeviceExecute[env, "Step", 
     trained[DeviceRead[env]["ObservedState"]]
```

instead?

The variable env was initialized by the code

```
env = DeviceOpen["SimulatedCartPole"]
```

and so in

```
DeviceExecute[env,"Step",_]
```

the blank should be either 'Right' or 'Left'.

Comment: I believe you are correct. I just had the same issue myself.